# how to prevent rawtype warnings in java program?

Tags: java

I am getting raw type warnings in my program.i used 
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes"),but it is more convenient if there some other method to resolve this issue.can anyone help me
i have this warning in the following code of NamingEnumeration part:

```
try {

        String[] attrIDs = { Constants.UNIQUEMEMBER };
        Attributes answer = iniDirContext.getAttributes("cn=" + groupName
                + "," + Constants.PROJECT_DN, attrIDs);
        NamingEnumeration ae = answer.getAll();
        Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();
        for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll(); e.hasMore();) {
            String str = e.next().toString();
            if (getAppUserRole(str))
                count = count + 1;

        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Which line has the warning?

Comment: Rawtype warnings usually result from not implicitly declaring your generic types on a class that utilizes them. For example declaring `List example = new ArrayList();` on `ArrayList<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use as `list1` `NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair>` instead of the raw type. The same goes for `results1` - use `NamingEnumeration<SearchResult>`. That way, you don't even have to cast.

Compare your code with this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); //raw typed
list.add("entry"); //add a string
String s = (String)list.get(0); //but return type is Object, because list in raw typed

ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); //strong typed
list2.add("entry"); //add a string
String s2 = list2.get(0); //return type is String, because list2 is strong typed
```

The whole code becomes:

```
SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list1 = iniDirContext.list(Constants.ORG_SEARCH_BASE);
while (list1.hasMore()) {
    String base = list1.next().getName() + "," + Constants.ORG_SEARCH_BASE; //no cast needed, list1 is strong typed
    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String filter = "(&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames))";
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results1 = iniDirContext.search(base, filter, searchControls);
    while (results1.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult searchResult = results1.next();
        Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
        Attribute cn = attributes.get(Constants.CN);
        Attribute address = attributes.get(Constants.POSTAL_ADDRESS);
        if (cn.get().equals(oranizationData.getOrgName()) && address.equals(oranizationData.getOrgAddress())) {
          return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are there any general method that can be applied for all rawtype warnings including List

Comment: You should never raw type your variables, allways strong type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<Class_Name>`, most likely on `NameClassPair`. Something like `NameClassPair<String, String>`.